# Domain Extensions - redirect from .com or .org to country side domain like .am

Tags: seo, domains, pagerank, domain-extension

i was wondering one thing.

Actually `.com` and all generic domain extensions specifies that the site is available for all countries while country side domain extensions like `.fm .mx or .sh` specifies to search engines that your site is developed for that specific country,

What if i buy 2 domains like `thisismysite.org` and `site.am` and then i  redirect `thisismysite.org` to `site.am` , will `site.am` be treated like a a general domain extension then?

OR i'll need anyway a generic domain to say to search engines that my site is generic all country sides available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the redirect is a 301 redirect, then google and duckduckgo, etc should ignore the *from* and use the *to*, if you get what I mean.  So whatever your *to* is  will be how the engine knows your site.

I think in general the A to your Q is no, or '*.am' will not be treated as '*.org'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in Google Webmaster Tools where you can choose target country. I think if you select target as USA which is for `.com` you will be kinda of generic.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst is correct that if you compare `example.com` with `example.it`, the last one it's likely to have a little bit more relevance **if** the hosted content is in Italian and the user is performing a search for an Italian context, there are a number of factors that may determine a linguistic relevance.

This means that there is nothing preventing you to host an Armenian site using a `.com` or `.net` extension.

To answer your question, if you purchase `example.am` and you host international content at that URL, the domain will be treated like an international context. This will happen regardless you will purchase `thisismysite.org` or not.

Keep in mind that is not the extension that determines the context of the domain. In some specific cases it may provide a small advantage, but in the majority of cases this is totally irrelevant.

There are plenty of sites using the `.io` or `.me` extension for English contents, when those extensions are expected to belong to British Indian Ocean Territory and Montenegro.